# Validation with symfony2 form and Model

Tags: php, facebook, forms, validation, symfony

I have a Model which have `token` field and a `choice` field type "userType".
This single form can be used to register user by following two ways:

1. Email and password - no use of token
2. Using Fb or G+ - need to pass token

I am in dilemma  where and how to check for the validation for token. In my mind I have two approaches as described below:

Approach 1:

Add token field in Form Type Class as an optional field and write a Custom Validation to check that if userType choice field value is "Fb" or "G+" check for token and throw exception accordingly.

Approach 2:

Write an Event Subscriber and check if userType choice field's value is "FB" or "G+" then only add token field dynamically as a required field. In this case I think I need to remove token from my Model(need suggestion on this also).

Please help me on this, any other suggestions or approaches are also welcomed.

Comment: Approach 2 is more preferable one. Every field that depends on data should be added using EventListener(subscriber). Why do you think you should remove token from a model?

Comment: @Ziumin I have confusion on that. 
I think when user registered using email & password in that case token field not added then what would be the value of token field in model?
If I remove it then in the case of Fb or G+ I wont be able to access it using my model object. So I that Case I need it.
What Should I do keep it in my model?

Comment: It depends. :) If you use one model object for username\password and fb users, u should keep both fields, but only in case of FB type you have token field to be mapped to form.

Comment: @AshishAwasthi I'd separate my Model into differnt models, 1 for system specific fields, others for 2 different authentication methods. Also, what if user creates two profiles (accounts), one by email/pass, one by FB? OR better if he/she wants one accout but two authentication types?

Comment: It should be decided on planning step of work. Usually, if user uses fb token with email that already exist in a system, it should be merged into one account. If you haven't such requirement, u can use separate objects.

Comment: @xurshid29 In My Application If user is registering with FB or G+ we fetch its email id and make an entry for it in our DB (if its not an existing one) and if user is going to register with same email id, we will prompt them with a message like already registered. User can login using Email/Password or FB G+ we will fetch the details from token and will allow them to use any of the methods to login with same email id.

Comment: @Ziumin yes I think Its a good idea to include the token field in both the cases with email / password it will be null and with FB or G+ "token" will be there.
Another thing I want to mention here that I am mentioning my validations in Model but with second approach I need to add Constraints in Form Subscriber Event itself for Token field Only.

Comment: Use different validation groups on different types.

Comment: @Ziumin that's really a good idea, Thanks a lot :D. I missed that will surely use it.